# How to destroy a nested resource instance in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I have nested resources:

```
#Nesting Resources
  resources :users do
    resources :photos do  
      resources :tags
    end
  end
```

In my view, I want to have a link to delete **tags**, but when clicking on it, the **Photo** is deleted instead.

```
<% if @photo.user === current_user %>
   <%= link_to "Eliminar", [@tag.photo.user,@tag.photo, @tag.id] , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Quieres borrar esto?'} %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE** 
This is where I need to get:

`DELETE  /users/:user_id/photos/:photo_id/tags/:id(.:format)     tags#destroy`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used `dependent: :destroy` in tag model?

Comment: No I didn't. I'll try it!

Comment: `belongs_to :photo, :dependent => :destroy` Didn't work, still erasing photos instead of tags..

Comment: What is the URL generated? When do do the request, what controller/action is logged on the output? What is the content of the action that is being executed? Have any of the models have [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) that are being called (like after_commit)?

Comment: URL generated is: 
"/users/11/photos/51/tags" which gives a Routing error:
`Routing Error
No route matches [DELETE] "/users/11/photos/51/tags"``

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Eliminar", "/users/#{@tag.photo.user.id}/photos/#{@tag.photo.id}/tags/#{@tag.id}" , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Quieres borrar esto?'} %>
```

Comment: It says `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/11/photos/49/tags"`

Comment: Pry says:

{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"photos", "user_id"=>"11", "id"=>"53"} .... No tag params are making the way.

Comment: Still the same. How can it be? It stops in the same route every time. 
http://localhost:3000/users/11/photos/21/tags/

I can't understand why isin't it getting to the tag itself.